# The logic of passing a missing argument to the R-function rep

Tags: r

The following R function

```
tmp <- function(p)
        rep(0, length.out = p)
```

puzzles me, since

```
> tmp()
[1] 0
```

I would expect an error in the call, since `p` is missing. The documentation for `rep` says that

*Function rep is a primitive, but (partial) matching of argument names is performed as for normal functions. You can no longer pass a missing argument to e.g. length.out.*

I don't understand the logic here. Why does `rep` seem to ignore that `p` is missing?

R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the documentation, I see:

> The default behaviour is as if the call was
>
> rep(x, times = 1, length.out = NA, each = 1)

But it does not apply for `rep.int`, which requires times argument:

```
>rep(0,)
[1] 0

>rep.int(0,)
Error in rep.int(0, ) : argument "times" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: OK, missingness is not an error because `rep` behaves as if `length.out` had default value `NA`. That makes sense, thanks. But what about the sentence *You can no longer pass a missing argument to e.g. length.out.*, which seems to contradict this logic.

Comment: Doesn't that just mean, that you, as a user, can not pass a missing argument? That it is impossible, since R will always put NA in its place? Maybe it just informs you about this behavior, instead or restricting certain operations (setting miising argument).

Comment: Maybe you are right. My reading was that I literally couldn't pass on a missing argument (that it would be an error). Thanks again.